# Eclipse doesn't show custom device in graphical layout view

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I've created a custom device with AVD manager and it runs fine on the emulator.

However, when I open a XML layout file and switch to graphical view, in the top of the view I want to select my custom device to view how the layout fits on it.

But my device doesn't appear in the list! And there's no way to select it. All I see is the standard devices: Nexus One, Nexus 7, Galaxy Nexus etc.

Am I missing something?

Comment: In the tab where You can choose devices, there must be a category "user". If You have created the device, close eclipse and open it again and it should appear in this category.

Comment: Indeed, it worked! Thanks! You should paste that in an answer and I'll mark it as winner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tab where You can choose devices, there must be a category "user". If You have created the device, close eclipse and open it again and it should appear in this category